# Why disable DNSSEC to get SSL certificates?

Tags: dns, domain

I'd like to know one thing regarding DNSSEC.

If I had a domain that I'd like to get an SSL certificate for, in a service that uses Let's Encrypt to issue certs for the domain name, why would they want me to disable DNSSEC?

I have seen several help sites where disabling DNSSEC was one of the requirements to issue certs or recommended when issuing the certs failed. Why exactly DNSSEC can cause problems here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing specific references to what you're talking about, its difficult to say for sure, but I found in most cases the problem is not DNSSEC itself, but misconfigured DNSSEC.

Since Lets Encrypt is using your DNS servers to validate ownership of a domain, if the server is misconfigured, Lets Encrypt uses that as a signal that something may be wrong and will refuse to issue the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Let's say the domain is hosted on Wix, I want them to proceed my cert, it doesn't end up, they suggest on the help sites to disable DNSSEC ([link](https://support.wix.com/en/article/troubleshooting-your-ssl-certificate)). Ok, so there is no technical limitation behind it, it's just a precaution. I'll try to find more about what the misconfigurations could be… That seems to be the key.